# How does flavor change in weak interaction works with $Z$ and $W^{\pm,0}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, definition

How does flavor change in weak interaction works with $Z$ and $W^{\pm,0}$?

I'm completely confused of how could weak interaction just "approximately" conserve the flavor, but $u,d,s,c$ could be just changed seemingly randomly.

For example, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Charged-current_interaction) showed that $W^-$ was used to mediate $d\rightarrow u$ and $c\rightarrow s$, where its decay contained $e^- +\overline{\nu}_e$...

Is there a default makeup(composition) of $W,Z$ at all? How could $W,Z$ just flip flavors without constrains? Is there any rule at all?

Comment: *" Is there any rule at all?"* Of course there are. But they are quantum mehcanical rules (real QM involving linear algebra and not just pop-sci QM). How is your preparation?

Comment: @dmckee right now, I got to quark byson, meson, strong interaction, and some simple fyremen diagram. We didn't talk about how to calculate the diagram yet...we talked about one need to integral of different diagram for the probability out come of a single process. What do you mean by integrate W and Z?

Comment: Imagine that I have a Stern-Gerlach experiment and I pass one of the separated beams into a second Stern-Gerlach apparatus rotated by, say, 2 degrees relative the first one. Do you know how to predict the relative strength of the resulting beams? That math is analogous to the flavor violation math for weak interactions, and you need to be comfortable with that before you start worrying about Feynman diagrams.

Comment: I finished quantum so no worries, but path integral is not taught in stranded QM.

Comment: The first step to answering this question is to ask, what is flavor, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is called quantum mechanics, it depends on the [postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) and the mathematical formulation with wave functions leading to probabilities of interaction.

If there is a probability non zero for a specific interaction, it will happen, in order  to fulfill the probability spectrum.

Probabilities are controlled not only by the form of the wavefunctions in the boundary conditions of the interaction, but also by conservation laws: energy, momentum, angular momentum, and a plethora of quantum number conservation as charge, baryon number , lepton number ... If these are conserved during the interaction, it will have a probability of happening.

In the specific case, the weak interaction does not conserve  flavor, charge and lepton number are, so if it is energetically possible, the quarks can change flavor through weak interaction.

The W and Z are elementary *point* particles in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. They are gauge bosons and carry no quantum numbers. In the link you gave note the example diagram. Weak interactions do not conserve flavor, so there is flavor change to an energetically (by the energy in the interaction) allowed one. Baryon number, lepton number  and charge are conserved in the weak interaction. The interaction shown has a probability of happening, that is why the neutron is not stable.